# Implement timer with angular2

Tags: angular

I have implemented a timer function in angularjs application as following:

```
$timeout($scope.startFilling, 30000)
    $scope.onTimeout = function(){

        $scope.counter1--; <= counter1 is initialized to 3
        mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);

        if($scope.counter1==0){
            $timeout.cancel(mytimeout);
            $scope.counter1=0
        }
    }

    var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);
```

I am basically calling a function after 30 seconds and the counter goes from 30 towards 0 and at 0 I cancel the timer.

I tried to implement it in angular2 as following:

```
start(){

        let timer = Observable.timer(3000,1000);
        this.myCounter = timer.subscribe(t=> this.startFilling(t));

    }

    startFilling(counter){

        this.counter1=--counter;
        if(this.counter1==0){

        this.myCounter.unsubscribe();
    }

    }
```

But this isn't totally working correct. I am binding counter1 (which is initialized to 3)on my template. `start()` function is called a button click and as soon as it is called, I want to decrease the counter1 from 3 to 0 and after 3 seconds I want to call `startFilling()` function. How can I do it?

Comment: this.myCounter.unsubscribe() should cancel the timer  ? shouldnt it ?
 whats the problem

Comment: I understood the unsubscribe part, but the counter value (counter1 which I am showing on template) is not being handled correctly somehow. I have initialized it to 3 and I expect it to go down till 0 and then end.

Comment: can u create plunkr or something ??

Comment: I also updated my question to be more descriptive

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/TV24p7PdLK7JPdZq3fZ1?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract one from the counter, unsubscribe when it reaches 0:

```
  tickerFunc(tick){
    this.counter1 = this.counter1 - 1;

     if(this.counter1==0){

      this.counter.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/nN3MlCzK6cCF6a7BjRnA?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

The counter is 0 based so you are setting counter1 to -1 and then 0. It is probably just easier to decrement counter1 by 1 each time in the subscription.

Comment: Could you perhaps show the code snippet how do suggest it? This is what I tried: http://plnkr.co/edit/TV24p7PdLK7JPdZq3fZ1?p=preview